# How to find openjdk version from C#?

Tags: java, c#, process, processstartinfo

I'm trying to find the version of the `OpenJDK` installed in the system through `C#` code.

I tried the following, it works for `Oracle's JDK`, but not for `OpenJDK`

```
 try
       {
           ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
           psi.FileName = "java.exe";
           psi.Arguments = " -version";
           psi.RedirectStandardError= true;
           psi.UseShellExecute = false;

           Process pr = Process.Start(psi);
           string strOutput = pr.StandardError.ReadLine().Split(' ')[2].Replace("\"", "");

           Console.WriteLine(strOutput);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Exception is " + ex.Message);
       }
```

if the output of `java -version` is

`openjdk version "1.8.0_202"`
    `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_202-b08)`
    `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)`

I want the output to be `1.8.0`

Comment: Can you explain in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: use regex `openjdk version \"(.*)\_`

Comment: try with string strOutput = pr.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

Comment: Readout Simple Explanation from [link]( https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1062118/Find-Java-Version-using-Csharp)